# Speaker does not alternate and only short beep under combined astable oscillation

Tags: circuit-analysis, speakers

Both oscillation work fine separately with SPKer

[image]

1. taking out R6, intermittent beep can be heard. Since current thru R5 is from time to time (decided by R3/C2 time factor).
2. taking out R5 beep sound is consistent since it is high frequency (even though sound is low-pitched) from R6-leading oscillation.

Q1: taking out C2, am I supposed to hear the same pitched sound as when taking out R5 since voltage drop across R6 or R4+R5 is the same. But it is actually not.  how does R4 in series with R5 and together in parallel to R6 affect oscillation different than R6 solely? why

Q2: taking out C2 I heard the consistent sound but when putting C2 back, I assume to hear 2 pitched sound alternating(since when R4 current directed to ground/negative when V2 on, and  I suppose to hear sound initiated by oscillation generated by current thru R6 alone and followed by V2 off with R4+R5/R6 current-generating oscillation and sound )without silence or stop. But I can ONLY hear the short beep with pitch like when C2 is taken out and then silence then again short beep. Why?

Q3: Is it the current in red right when V2 is off and how to analyze how much current from R4 going to C2 as it is meanwhile feeding R5 on the right?

Comment: Can I just check that it's an ordinary moving-coil speaker, not a piezo speaker or anything else?

Comment: it is an ordinary coil speaker.

Answer (score 1):

The problems are caused by the instability of the second (complementary) astable, the base resistor of the first transistor is too small. For the stability of the second astable, replace the resistor R6 with a larger one than 100 kΩ  (220 kΩ is suitable). You can set the frequency with C3. To limit the base current of V4, add an extra resistor between V3 collector and V4 base (330 Ω). (The reference marks refer to the your schematic.)
[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, it works. one more question, how to decide what range of resistor to be used to make this circuit work?   2,   how to read your curve graph? can you give more explanation on your 2nd snapshot.

Comment: btw, can you recommend what software you are using to mimic this circuit, can it detect current, voltage at any locations and even output the oscillation picture?

Comment: Unfortunately, the usable resistance range is highly dependent on the parameters of the specific transistor. It is advisable to use a trimmer potentiometer instead of a resistor to ensure stable operation. There are several types of simulator programs, here I just used the free simulator TINA-TI. https://www.ti.com/tool/TINA-TI

Comment: highly appreciate it.  it helped a lot.